# How to break in nested foreach loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two lists with the same length. I need to iterate so that the first item in the list A matches the first item in the list B. For that I've created a nested foreach loop, that looks like this:

```
$nodes_table = "a","b","c"
$nodes_list = "a","b","c"

     :Outer foreach ($item in $nodes_table) {
        foreach($node in $nodes_list)
        {
            if($node -eq $item)
            {
                Write-Output "$node hostname matches in vTM"
                break :Outer
            }           
        }        
    }
```

**Problem:**
In the first iteration, it matches. But in the second iteration, the inner loop doesn't go to the second item, it resets again.

```
First iteration: $node = a equals $item = a
Second iteration: $node = a not equals to $item = b.
```

As you can see, in the second iteration inner loop didn't iterate, it reset back to a.

Comment: Please don't add the [tag:c#] tag to a powershell question. They are not the same language

Comment: "As you can see, in the second iteration inner loop didn't iterate, it reset back to a".  How can we see this?  Your code doesn't produce that output.

Comment: Why not a `For` loop? `For($i=0;$i -lt $nodes_table.count;$i++){"nodes_table: $($nodes_table[$i]) - nodes_list: $($nodes_list[$i])"}`

Comment: Camilo, c# solution would also give me a clue about my problem. But thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks for your input, I guess for loop also works in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems here. First, if you have a label like`:Outer foreach(...` the name of the label is just `Outer` so when you reference it in a `break` statement, you specify `break Outer` not `break :Outer` (might just be a typo). Second, you need to use the `continue` statement not the `break` statement. The `continue` statement resumes execution at the next iteration. The updated code looks like:

```
$nodes_table = "a","b","c"
$nodes_list = "a","b","c"

:Outer foreach ($item in $nodes_table) {
    foreach($node in $nodes_list)
    {
        if($node -eq $item)
        {
            Write-Output "$node hostname matches in vTM"
            continue Outer
        }           
    }        
}
```

Comment: In this case, `break`-ing the inner `for` and `continue`-ing to the outer `for` produce the same results.

Comment: No. If you run the above code with `break` only the first match is emitted. If you run it with `continue`, all three matches will be printed. It's only when your code **uses the invalid label** `:Outer`  starting with a colon does it look the same. Completely removing the break/continue statement will produce the same result because the inner and outer loops both run to completion. But the goal is to short-circuit the inner loop on a match, so you need to use `continue` with the correct label.

Comment: I think you miss my point.  As originally written in the __question__, above, the code does indeed behave exactly as the code you've submitted as an answer, and it's very easy to throw them both into the PS ISE and prove that.

Comment: You're right - the code works correctly because of the bug and  because there is no code after the inner loop  In fact a simple unlabeled break is all that is necessary. However if there was code after the inner loop, the `continue` statement would be needed.

Comment: Having colon before :Outer is a right syntax in the outer for loop?

Comment: Yes having the colon is the right syntax. In fact it's required because the colon is needed to distinguish a label from a command. For example, `:dir` with a colon is a label named "dir" whereas `dir` without the colon is the `dir` command.

Comment: I get     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException on the :outer line.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your example code as follows:

```
$nodes_table = "a","b","c"
$nodes_list = "a","b","c"

:Outer foreach ($item in $nodes_table) 
{
    foreach($node in $nodes_list)
    {
        Write-Output "item = $item, node = $node" # display values being compared
        if($node -eq $item)
        {
            Write-Output "$node hostname matches in vTM"
            break :Outer
        }           
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
item = a, node = a
a hostname matches in vTM
item = b, node = a
item = b, node = b
b hostname matches in vTM
item = c, node = a
item = c, node = b
item = c, node = c
c hostname matches in vTM
```

Looks to me like it's behaving correctly.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Bruce Payette's answer below, there is a defect in the original code that I copied into my example above.  The `break :Outer` statement is incorrect, because the object of a break should either be nothing or the name of a label.  The colon (:) character should not be there.  PowerShell ignores this error and behaves as if there is no label on the `break` statement, thereby breaking the inner loop, not the outer loop. Removing the colon, which makes the line `break Outer`, you will see that the code jumps immediately to the end of the outer `for` loop during the first iteration of the outer loop and the first iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: Huh, I figured it works. But why in the second iteration it checks b vs a? and then b vs b?

Comment: @Hashim77 That is how scoping works. The inner `ForEach` loop is specific to the current iteration (the scope) of the outer `ForEach` loop, so when the outer loop moves from 'a' to 'b' it disposes of the inner loop from the 'a' scope, and creates a new one for the 'b' scope.